# How to write a query in (Jira Query Languange) to restrict issues by week number?

Tags: jira, jql

I have the query written in [Jira Query Language](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql)

```
assignee was brad and status was WIP DURING ("2019/1/20", "2019/1/26")
```

which works but I'd rather write

```
assignee was brad and status was WIP DURING week("2019", 4)
```

which is easier to formulate. Is this possible in JQL?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately JQL doesn't provide a function returning the time period of a given calendar week.

To not always having to look up the begin/end dates of each calendar week one could think of a workaround using the [`startOfYear()`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicedeskcloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-780868134.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-startOfYearstartOfYear()) function. Your example would be in that case:

```
assignee was brad and status was WIP DURING (startOfYear("4w"), startOfYear("5w"))
```

Comment: That has the same problem as startOfWeek as all the queries are relative to NOW so startOfYear will be the current year. I guess what is required is "2018+1w".

Comment: In your questions was not specified that you are interessted in the calendar weeks of PREVIOUS years. This is unfortunately not supported. There are ugly workarounds (compare something like [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-questions/How-to-search-for-first-week-of-prior-year/qaq-p/55670) but those will be more complex as using the dates

Comment: I updated the question to make this clear. The use case is for generating weekly reports and once generated they always return the same data. I know I could generate PDF or raw html reports but that is a different issue.